# Find max int key in hashmap kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

```
val myDict : HashMap<Int, String> = hashMapOf( 0 to "zero", 1 to "one", 2 to "two" )
```

I have to find maximum Int key value of myDict HashMap.
something like this:

```
myDict.getMaxKey() // should be 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this :

```
myDict.keys.maxOrNull()
```

Api reference : [`keys`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/keys.html), [`maxOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-or-null.html)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Tom's answer, if you want to have the Map entry and not only the key, you can do something as follows:

```kotlin
myDict.maxByOrNull { it.key })
```

Comment: And to answer the OP's question: `myDict.maxByOrNull { it.key }?.value`. (That's _if_ the wording "I have to find maximum Int key value" is to be interpreted as "I have to find the value associated with the maximum int key". But the question can be interpreted in other ways too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are repeatedly looking for the max key in a Map, you should consider using a TreeMap instead of a HashMap, if possible.

Other answers, such as `myDict.maxByOrNull { it.key })`, will iterate through all entries in the HashMap. This can be very inefficient.

If you have a TreeMap (or, more generally, a SortedMap), you can do this instead:

```
myDict.lastEntry()
```

which is going to be very fast as it goes straight to the maximum entry in the sorted map.